# Using linq to extract titles from sitemap files

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and LINQ to be able to extract all `title` attributes of all `siteMapNode` elements in a [web.sitemap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx) file, regardless of depth? Any examples of how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: Something like `document..siteMapNode@title`. I don't really remember the syntax that well.

Comment: Okay, the syntax is `document...<siteMapNode>.@title`, and apparently you'd have to switch to VB.NET to use it, so do that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/web.sitemap"));
    var urlList = xelement.Descendants().Attributes()
       .Where(x => x.Name == "title")
       .Select(x => x.Value);

    foreach (string s in urlList)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sitemapfile = File.ReadAllText("path of web.sitemap");

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sitemapfile);

var elements = doc.Root.Elements("siteMapNode");
foreach (var elem in elements) {
    if (elem.Attribute("title") != null)
         {
        //do your work
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's much easier to use plain old XPath.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(contentsOfFile);
doc.XPathEvaluate("//@title");
foreach (var element in ((IEnumerable)result).Cast<XAttribute>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has value {1}", element.Name, element.Value);
}
```